# Why #pragma warning disable S2068 does not work?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have the following piece of code in a tool:

```
var o = new OptionSet()
    .Add("password=|pwd=|p=", "The database password. Only when using SQL authentication.", p => password = p.TrimQuotes())
    ...
;
```

My PR build promotes Sonar warnings to compilation errors and so the code fails with:

```
HashPasswordsArgs.cs(49,22): warning S2068: "password" detected here, make sure this is not a hard-coded credential. [C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswords.csproj]
```

OK, I know it is a false positive and want to suppress it in code (this is my specific and conscious desire, please do not suggest going to the SonarQube server to do anything).

I tried adding the `//NOSONAR` (with or without a space after //), I also tried adding `#pragma warning disable S2068` at the top of the file. Nothing helps.

What am I missing?

Here are the example runs:

**//NOSONAR**

```
C:\xyz\HashPasswords [master ≡]> cat .\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswordsArgs.cs |sls SONAR

                .Add("password=|pwd=|p=", "The database password. Only when using SQL authentication.", p => password = p.TrimQuotes()) //NOSONAR


C:\xyz\HashPasswords [master ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
HashPasswordsArgs.cs(49,22): warning S2068: "password" detected here, make sure this is not a hard-coded credential. [C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswords.csproj]
  HashPasswords -> C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\bin\Debug\net472\HashPasswords.exe
  Sonar: (HashPasswords.csproj) Project processed successfully

Build succeeded.

HashPasswordsArgs.cs(49,22): warning S2068: "password" detected here, make sure this is not a hard-coded credential. [C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswords.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.23
C:\xyz\HashPasswords [master ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]>
```

**#pragma warning disable S2068**

```
C:\xyz\HashPasswords [master ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]> dir .\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswordsArgs.cs |sls S2068

src\HashPasswords\HashPasswordsArgs.cs:6:#pragma warning disable S2068


C:\xyz\HashPasswords [master ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
HashPasswordsArgs.cs(51,22): warning S2068: "password" detected here, make sure this is not a hard-coded credential. [C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswords.csproj]
  HashPasswords -> C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\bin\Debug\net472\HashPasswords.exe
  Sonar: (HashPasswords.csproj) Project processed successfully

Build succeeded.

HashPasswordsArgs.cs(51,22): warning S2068: "password" detected here, make sure this is not a hard-coded credential. [C:\xyz\HashPasswords\src\HashPasswords\HashPasswords.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.28
C:\xyz\HashPasswords [master ≡ +1 ~2 -0 !]>
```

I am interested to know why #pragma does not work. Any other code based suppression is welcome. The more focused the better, i.e. ideally I just want to suppress this one warning on the particular line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below should work.

`[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Sonar Code Smell", "S2068:Credentials should not be hard-coded", Justification = "<Pending>")]`

It worked with below attribute for me as well
[SuppressMessage("Sonar Code Smell", "S2068:Credentials should not be hard-coded", Justification = "")]

Comment: It does work. Although `#pragma` and `//NOSONAR` looked more promising, because they could disable it for the specific line in code, whereas the attribute is applied to the whole function. But in the absence of better alternative I will take that.

Comment: @mark You can be more specific with the exclusion attribute in the `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file setting the `Scope` and `Targe` property. For example: `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Sonar Code Smell", "S2068:Credentials should not be hard-coded", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "member", Target = "~HashPasswords.HashPasswordsArgs")]`